# I can't use a nested loop as foreach

Tags: php, foreach, nested

The problem is easy. The answer is not

I have an array with multiple (2) dimensions. 
The code is easy (line 28-32):

```
<?php
foreach($select_all_data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $v => $k) {
        $all_values = $v.",";
    }
}
?>
```

But when I excecute it, it shows me 
`Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\qlb\test.php on line 29`

(I also tested $value al array with `is_array`, that gave me true)

An example output of $value in the loop is:

`array(12) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "101"
  ["aangever_voornaam"]=>
  string(8) "censored"
  ["aangever_achternaam"]=>
  string(6) "censored"
  ["aangever_geslacht"]=>
  string(3) "Male"
  ["pleegplaats"]=>
  string(6) "censored"
  ["pleegdatum"]=>
  string(10) "dd-mm-yyyy"
  ["pleegtijd"]=>
  string(5) "hh:mm"
  ["verbalisant"]=>
  string(12) "censored"
  ["verklaring"]=>
  string(229) "censored"
  ["opnamedatum"]=>
  string(19) "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
  ["status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["behandelaar"]=>
  string(12) "censored"
}`

As you can see, its a nice array that I want to put in the loop. But it gives me the invalid argument error.

What did I do wrong?

For the record: I tried to create a script to export a whole database with this script

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "";
$DB_USER = "";
$DB_PASS = "";
$DB_NAME = "";

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

$select_all_tables = array();
$select_all_data = array();
$show_tables_from = $con->query("SHOW TABLES FROM `$DB_NAME`");
while ($row = $show_tables_from->fetch_assoc()) {
    $select_all_tables[] = $row['Tables_in_'.$DB_NAME.''];
}
foreach ($select_all_tables as $a) {
    $q = $con->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE `$a`");
    $show_create_table[] = $q->fetch_assoc()['Create Table'];
    $q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `$a`");
    $select_all_data[] = $q->fetch_assoc();
}
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($a);
//var_dump($show_create_table);
//var_dump($select_all_data);
foreach($select_all_data as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible that some `$value` s are arrays and some are not?

Comment: @jh1711 That is'nt possible. I've added is_array in the loop and they all show true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrays had a diffrent number of keys. I think because I forgot to loop the query in the first foreach (after the while)

So I changed that to

```
foreach ($select_all_tables as $a) {
    $q = $con->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE `$a`");
    $show_create_table[] = $q->fetch_assoc()['Create Table'];
    $q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `$a`");
    while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
        $select_all_data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

And that was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [`fetch_assoc` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or
>   NULL if there are no more rows.

So for those `$value` elements inside the loop that end up being null you will have that error thrown..

So just wrap it in `if` statement like:

```
if (!is_null($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $v => $k) {
        $all_values = $v.",";
    }
}
```

or maybe even `is_array($value)` to make sure you able to iterate thru...

Comment: if `$row` is null, the while loop will end, and the null won't be appended to the array.